# How to get previous changeset id of a specific file

Tags: mercurial

I would like to get the previous revision for a specific file, no matter if it was changed in the tip or not.

For example, I have a repo that has a tip at changeset 226

```
$:~/sandbox$ hg log -r -3::.
changeset:   224:591c7a48b15f
user:        blah <blah.com>
date:        Tue May 28 09:07:25 2013 -0700
summary:     TEST: test

changeset:   225:8c3689dedfa8
user:        blah <blah.com>
date:        Tue May 28 09:07:53 2013 -0700
summary:     TEST: test2

changeset:   226:88f5ee46f99b
tag:         tip
user:        blah <blah.com>
date:        Tue May 28 09:42:46 2013 -0700
summary:     TEST:test
```

Inside that repo is a file called doit that was changed a while ago, at changeset 158:

```
$:~/projects/sandbox$ hg log  doit
changeset:   158:8536d2b52f24
user:        blah <blah.com>
date:        Thu May 03 18:56:50 2012 -0700
summary:     TEST: clean up buiild

changeset:   121:82313616d631
user:        blah <blah.com>
date:        Wed Apr 06 14:04:55 2011 -0700
summary:     scr3: created program to test UI tests in Hudson

changeset:   116:c668d2a9c2b2
user:        blah <blah.com>
date:        Tue Feb 15 11:31:31 2011 -0800
summary:     TEST: add another line

changeset:   115:9affabd80774
user:        blah <blah.com>
date:        Tue Feb 15 11:21:01 2011 -0800
summary:     TEST: modify doit

changeset:   114:4097920e7edb
user:        blah <blah.com>
date:        Tue Feb 15 11:18:58 2011 -0800
summary:     TEST: add doit
```

And I can dump the contents of the file using hg cat:

```
$:~/projects/sandbox$ hg cat -r 158 doit
#! /bin/sh

echo doit for the sandbox hudson test job...
echo add another line out
echo add yet another line...

#ant clean build
```

So far so good. The question is how do I specify the previous revision of the file (doit) without explicitly specifying "158". (I'd have to search the hg log output for it for example).

I've tried:

```
hg log -r -2 doit
hg log -r "ancestor(.)" doit
hg log -r "ancestor(file(doit))"
hg log -r "limit(file(doit))"
hg log -r "limit(file(doit)~0)"
(etc.)
```

I finally tried this one which seems to work:

```
$:~/sandbox$ hg log -r "last(file(doit))"
changeset:   158:8536d2b52f24
```

But when I tried it against another repo and file:

```
$:~/projects/otherrepo$ hg log -r "last(file(file-version))"
hg: parse error: file requires a pattern
```

It seems the dash "-" is causing a syntax issue. I tried escaping it:

```
$:~/projects/otherrepo$ hg log -r "last(file(uic\-version))"
hg: parse error at 13: syntax error
```

Any ideas on what to try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different type of escaping:

```
hg log -r 'last(file("uic-version"))'
```

Comment: It worked! I also tried it with a file with embedded spaces: hg log -r 'last(file("doc/some log file name with spaces.doc"))'